# Do views inherit indexes created from tables?

Tags: oracle11g

I have two views in Oracle SQL, one with 400 million records and the other with 100 million records.

I have a performance problem with the query and I think it's because of the views.

In the tables that use the views, I have created several indices, my question is: Do the views that use the queries inherit the indexes created in the source tables?

Comment: You can answer this question yourself easily enough.  Just run the view, then run the SQL inside the view separately, and compare the performances.  They should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

For a non materialized view, my understanding is that running it will just query the underlying tables, and, if those tables have indices, they would be used.

Generally speaking, a view's performance depends on the underlying tables which it uses.

A materialized view can also have an index, but you would need to define it.